# CSS horizontal nav bar displaying diagonally in IE 5.5 - 7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The nav bar displays the correct way (horisontally) in IE 8 and above and every other browser. However only IE 5.5, 6 and 7 it displays diagonally. Can any body help?

```
.top-nav ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

.top-nav li {
margin-left: 220px;
}

.top-nav a {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 38px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 4px 30px 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 34px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}

.top-nav a:hover {
background:  #272727;
color: #18942f;
}

.top-nav .current_page_item a {
background:  #252525;
color: #FFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="top-nav"> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="index.html" class="links">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href="aboutme.html" class="links">About Me</a></li> 
    <li><a href="skills.html" class="links">Skills</a></li> 
    <li class="current_page_item"> <a href="#">Contact</a></li> 
    </ul> 
</div>
```

[image: here's a screenshot]

Comment: I have never heard this one before! Do you mean vertically? Can you give us a test case?

Comment: IE 6 and 7 should be supported, but how do you even know what it looks like in 5.5? AFAIK in IE9 you can only simulate as bad as IE6... Which luckily, [only about 6% of the world still uses](http://www.ie6countdown.com/).

Comment: I use IETester which has IE5.5 and it displays perfect in IE9. I go into some offices sometimes who are still using IE6 so i still think its important

Comment: Wow seriously, someone is still testing their site in IE5.5??? I'll give you credit for going above and beyond the call of duty, but honestly, I think you may be wasting your time. In fact, if this is a personal homepage (as the screenshot appears to be), I wouldn't even bother with IE6 or IE7. You only need to worry about those browsers if you're working for a company that can't be bothered to upgrade and insists on keeping their old browser. No-one else is using anything less than IE8 these days, and the six people who are using them are used to seeing sites that don't work properly.

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester - 6% worldwide maybe, but that's only if you exclude China, it's more like 0.6% or less.

Comment: @Spudley think you meant "include", but that is indeed an important detail. Since half their internet is censored and based on how some chinese sites look, I think that IE6 can indeed be completely disregarded nowadays. There's a line to be drawn where developers should accommodate for users, or users should be wise enough to upgrade their software which is sometimes just necessary... Your explanation about companies is quite right.

Comment: ok then, thanks for your comments I will just leave it alone. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of floating each link, why not use display:inline on your li, display: inline works on IE 5.5

Also you need to remove "display: Block" as this is what is causing the links to move down.

```
.top-nav ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

.top-nav li {
 display: inline;
}

.top-nav a {
height: 38px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 4px 30px 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 34px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
color: #aaa;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YJjya/

---

If you need to have your items be blocks, then use inline-block. Workaround to make it work on older version or IE can be found here: [Work Around Inline Block](http://work.arounds.org/issue/18/using-inline-block-ie7-and-ie6/)

---

Also here is a handy piece of code to place immediately after your first head tag. It will only display is the user is using IE 7 or later and will tell them get their sh*t together and download a new browser. It is really not worth the time trying to make your site work on every IE version as you'll end up pulling your hair out to please a few people who obviously aren't internet savvy to begin with. As Mario said only 6% of the world still use IE6... But if you take a closer look at countries such as the US or UK that number is below 1%

### After Head

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser. <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

### CSS

```
.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}
```

Comment: I once did a site for a restaurant that after going live had people calling everyday to say they couldn't access the site...

I couldn't understand why until I checked IE 5.5... People in offices don't really have an option but to use what is provided for them. In most cases I would use the HTML Boiler Plate Update Script but in this case it would have meant a lose in business so had no choice but to try and fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this problem many times. You want to float the LI and not the A that's inside the LI.

All you need to do is remove [float:left] from [.top-nav a] class and add it to the [.top-nav li] class.  Your CSS would be:

```
.top-nav ul {
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

.top-nav li {
margin-left: 220px;
float: left;
}

.top-nav a {
display: block;
height: 38px;
margin-right: 1px;
padding: 4px 30px 0 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 34px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
}

.top-nav a:hover {
background:  #272727;
color: #18942f;
}

.top-nav .current_page_item a {
background:  #252525;
color: #FFF;
}
```